# Docrtine Many to Many count without inverseBy

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a fairly simple products database where a brand has many products and colours, and a product has one or more colours.

I'd like to select all the colours with a the brand entity and a count of all products using that particular colour in a single query otherwise I'll end up with 30+ queries a page load!

**Doctrine entities**

Brand

```
class Brand
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $brandId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, unique=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="brand")
     */
    protected $products;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Colour", mappedBy="brand")
     */
    protected $colours;
}
```

Product

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $productId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brandId", referencedColumnName="brandId", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $brand;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Colour")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="productColours",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="productId", referencedColumnName="productId")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="colourId", referencedColumnName="colourId")}
     * )
     */
    protected $colours;
}
```

Colour

```
class Colour
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $colourId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand", inversedBy="colours")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brandId", referencedColumnName="brandId", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $brand;
 }
```

This in plain SQL this is really easy...

```
SELECT c.*, b.*, count(p.productId) as productCount 
FROM colours c
INNER JOIN brands b ON c.brandId = b.brandId
LEFT JOIN productColours pc ON pc.colourId = c.colourId
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.productId = pc.productId
GROUP BY c.colourId
```

In Doctrine I can't find a way around this without adding bidirectional mapping into colours which I really don't want just for a product count.

My current query looks something like this (which doesn't work as theres no c.products mapping).

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select(
        'c AS colour',
        'b AS brand',
        'COUNT(DISTINCT p.productId) AS productCount'
    )
    ->from('Colour', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.brand', 'b')
    ->leftJoin('c.products', 'p');
```

Also assuming the above would not map the brand into the colour entity so I couldn't go `$colour->getBrand()`?

Comment: Why do you prefer not having bidirectional associations? Is it perhaps the performance that you are concerned about?

Comment: Throughout the project there will be many occasions where I want to achieve this same task. Seems crazy to do bidirectional just for a count.

Comment: Bidirectional associations do nothing wrong if properly mapped. See my answer below.

Comment: Could you explain why do you think it would be *crazy* to use a bidirectional association? I am intrigued :)

Comment: I'm estimating around 20-30 occasions that I'm going to find myself in this scenario. That seems like an awful lot of code for something that can be done in a simple SQL query. Starting to think native SQL and result set mapping might be the best approach for my specific case!

Comment: There is not much difference in the amount of code. You can create the bidirectional association (2 lines) and then create a method in your entity's repository to do the count (some ~7 lines). This seems to me to be the more elegant solution. Alternatively you can run a `native sql query` as suggested in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a native sql query with doctrine to achieve your objective. See an example here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

The second option would be to ***use*** bidirectional associations. If performance is your concern you can enable the `LAZY` or `EXTRA_LAZY` fetch modes. Thus the performance will be minimally affected if at all.

More on `extra lazy` associations: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

In doctrine associations are considered lazy by default. This means that the entities will be fully loaded only if used (ie. property access, search, etc).

The `extra lazy` fetch mode diminishes even more the number of method which trigger a full entity hydration.